# We are going to movies at eight tomorrow. Is this possible?

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-continuous

I (non-native speaker) am studying about present tenses for the future.
We can use present simple or present continuous for the future events. So I wonder...

1. My train **leaves** at 11.  (I think this is ok)
2. My train **is leaving** at 11. (Is this correct?)

A. We **are going to** the movies tomorrow. (I think this is ok)
B. We **are going to** the movies at eight tomorrow . (Is this correct?) 
C. We **go to** the movies at eight tomorrow . (Is this correct?)
D. We **go to** the movies tomorrow. (Is this correct?)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is correct. This is generally the form used when speaking of a recurrent pattern ("I take the train to work daily. My train leaves at 11.").

(2) is correct.  This is generally the form used when speaking of a particular trip.

(A) is correct.

(B) was correct as you originally posted it, but the edit is also correct. The difference is a subtle one of emphasis on the time.

(C) should not be considered correct. This would normally be expressed as you did in (B) above.

(D) should not be considered correct. This would normally be expressed as you did in (A) above.

Note that for (C) and (D), if you were speaking of a recurrent pattern, for example "We go to the movies every Monday [at eight].", the construction would be correct. The difference is discussing a particular instance versus a recurrent pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry 'B' is My train is leaving at 11 not 'My train are ~'.  So 'B' is possible, especially in grammar?

Comment: Yes. With the correction, you are correctly speaking of a particular trip.

Comment: C and D are possible, acceptable, and really not that unusual: *Let me check the schedule...yes, we go to dinner at 5 tomorrow, and to the movies at 8.*

Comment: I am curious about A and B. Should we add a verb after going to? like, We are going to 'see' the movies tomorrow. 'Be going to' plays a role as 'will', so there is no verb in the sentence or the verb 'see' is omitted? Can someone give some advise on this?

Comment: @dan: we can add another verb but don't need to.  **going to** is not a mere substitute for *will* when the complement is a *destination* or takes place at a destination.  *We're going to the beach on Saturday.* *We're going to the game on Saturday.* *We're going to the movies on Saturday.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: so, those are the examples for 'present continuous for the future events', right?